# DPDA by empty stack

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

Let's say we have DPDA with acceptance by empty stack, *w* is accepted by this DPDA. Why can't *wv* be accepted? I know about the prefix property but i don't see where it's coming from. Can't we just continue moving after reading *w* when the stack is empty until we read the whole input and decide whether we accept the word by looking at the stack state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transition in a PDA always needs to read a symbol in the stack. If there is no symbol, there is no transition.

Since the PDA is deterministic, reading $w$ will **always** reach a configuration with an empty stack, and no transition can permit to read any non empty word.